# Starting amqp-consume on Debian 8

Tags: amqp, rabbitmqctl

I used to consume messages from amqp-consume with this command below at debian 7, but I installed debian 8 I think the amqp-tools is different and it does not recognize my command.

I noticed some changes. My web interface change the port from 55672 to 15672.

```
amqp-consume -d -q queue.udrive.admin.uiscsi -s 10.0.1.251 -p 5672 -e "directExchangeUdrive" --vhost "/" -r "" --username=guest --password=guest /bin/bash remoteManageUiSCSI.sh
error: both --server and --url options specify server host
```

I think the command expects it:

```
amqp-consume 
consuming command not specified
Usage: amqp-consume [-dxA?] [-u|--url=amqp://...] [-s|--server=hostname] [--port=port] [--vhost=vhost] [--username=username] [--password=password] [--ssl] [--cacert=cacert.pem] [--key=key.pem] [--cert=cert.pem] [-q|--queue=queue] [-e|--exchange=exchange] [-r|--routing-key=routing key] [-d|--declare] [-x|--exclusive] [-A|--no-ack] [-c|--count=limit] [-p|--prefetch-count=limit] [-?|--help] [--usage] [OPTIONS]... <command> <args>
```

I tried all kinds of things on amqp:// and it dodn't work.

Comment: Check which librabbitmq version used. These tools comes with it. If in doubt - check the source of amqp-consume - https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/tools/consume.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer at other site https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.30/programming/book/QpidJNDI.html but I still wonder to know why this answer was not at the "man amqp-consume" or rabbitmq web site....

The command works for me is:

```
amqp-consume -d -u amqp://test:test@ustorageprod/%2f -q queue.udrive.admin.uiscsi -e "directExchangeUdrive" -r "" /bin/bash remoteManageUiSCSI.sh

amqp-publish -u amqp://test:test@ustorageprod/%2f -r "queue.udrive.ustorage" -e "directExchangeUdrive" -b "$msg"
```